# Eclipse maven externalToolBuilder

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven project, and i'm surprised that .project and .externalToolsBuilder are under svn.
Someone explain to me that its because we need to create a builder automaticaly when developer's import project under eclipse.

Does it possible to add in pom.xml all that i need to create this builder when project is imported into eclipse wihout need to commit .project file?

Because i want to have a clean directory without .project/.classpath etc... before import my project and i don't want this file under svn

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is clearly "yes". It is possible to set up Eclipse from a pom.xml file and have Eclipse generate the files it needs from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate the `.project` file, but not the files in the `.externalToolBuilders` folder. And if you have custom builders those should be added with `<additionalBuildcommands>`. See [eclipse maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html).

So, the `.project` file shouldn't sit in svn, `.externalToolBuilders`. You can generate those too, as you can see in the [eclipse maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html), but the content still has to be somewhere (your pom, a server etc).